# different results when using g++ and visual studio 14 2015 compilers with regex in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, g++

I was playing with regex in c++ when I noticed some irregularities between the g++ (MinGW) and the Visual Studio 14 2015 compiler (both on Windows). Here is the code I tried it with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

static const std::string data = "\n    a = 10\n    b = 20\n";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto strIt = data.begin();

    while (strIt != data.end())
    {
        std::regex e("^[ \t\n\r]");
        std::smatch m;
        std::string s(strIt, data.end());

        if (std::regex_search(s, m, e))
        {
            strIt += m[0].str().size();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "s = \"" << s << "\"" << '\n';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When compiling with g++ I get the expected output of

```
s = "a = 10\n    b = 20\n"
```

but when using the visual studio compiler, it spits out

```
s = "b = 20\n"
```

ignoring the whole "a = 10" part. After investigating further in visual studio via the debug functionality, I saw that the m variable was holding the space from after the "a = 10" part.

Do you know why it behaves like that? Am I making a big mistake somewhere while not noticing it? Please help.

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem - but you don't have to create `s`, you can do `regex_search(strIt, data.end(), m, e);`

Comment: Yes, now it should output everything fine. I'm sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a simplified example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const string data = "abc\nXabc";
    regex re("^X");
    smatch match;
    if (regex_search(data, match, re))
        cout << "match: " << match.str() << endl;
    else
        cout << "no match" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio 2015 outputs:

> match: X

MinGW 7.1.0 outputs:

> no match

---

So, the difference cuts down to whether `^` in the regular expression matches starts of lines or only the beginning of the string. In C++ 17 it is determined by the `regex::flag_type` argument passed to the `regex` constructor.

[31.5.1 Bitmask type syntax_­option_­type](http://eel.is/c++draft/re.synopt):

> The type syntax_­option_­type is an implementation-defined bitmask type. Setting its elements has the effects listed in Table 130. A valid value of type syntax_­option_­type shall have at most one of the grammar elements ECMAScript, basic, extended, awk, grep, egrep, set. If no grammar element is set, the default grammar is ECMAScript.
>
> ---
>
> Table 130 — syntax_­option_­type effects
>
> ...
>
> multiline — Specifies that ^ shall match the beginning of a line and $ shall match the end of a line, if the ECMAScript engine is selected.

In order for `^` to match starts of lines, the `regex` object needs to initialized like this:

```
regex re("^X", regex_constants::multiline);
```

---

In conclusion, MinGW's behavior is correct under the C++ 17 Standard.

Comment: So there is no way to get the same behaviour on visual studio? I guess I will just have to replace every newline with a space.

Comment: @Ugi You can use `regex_match` instead of `regex_search`.